# Error when uploading mp3 using PHP

Tags: php, audio, upload, submit, mp3

I have a form on a webpage that allows users to upload mp3 files. It works perfectly fine except when it comes to files over 2MB. Then it says "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file." I have tested mp3s ranging from 2mb - 6mb and they dont work and I believe I have adjusted the code to where it can accept files well over 2MB. Can someone help?

Here's the HTML, (I don't believe this to be the issue):

```
<div id="contactpara">
<form id="upform" action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Music" name="submit">
    <iframe id="upload_target" name="upload_target" src="" style="width:500px;height:100px;border:0px solid #000;"></iframe>
</form>
</div>
```

Here's the PHP:

```
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 10000000000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "mp3" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only mp3 files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
?>
```

The reason it says $imageFileType is because this was a PHP code used to accept images that I tweaked to accept audio files. Could this be causing the issue? Please let me know.

Comment: given that the only place you could possibly get your particular error message is if the `move_uploaded_file()` call fails, you should be looking at WHY it fails.

Comment: perhaps your server config only allows for files up to 2mb.  use `ini_get('upload_max_filesize');` to check this in PHP.

Comment: @MichaelDoye thank you for that! I simply just had to add this to my php.ini :   post_max_size = 50M
upload_max_filesize = 50M and that solved the issue

Answer (score -1):

I kind of had this same issue and found out it was the max_filesize which was 2m. it makes me think alot cus i troubleshooted.. solution is just to change the max_filesize to the amount you want